# javascript: React - limit number of components (or columns) rendered per row in a loop/map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, layout

I know it seems quite easy... But I can't figure out how to get it. So, any suggestion is truly welcome. Thanks.

**What I have**

I am using React.js. I have an array of elements (let's say 20).

**What I want**

I want to render 4 elements (for example) per row.

**Wha the problem is**

I can't figure out how to limit the amount of components/columns per row.

This code render all components in a row... How can I limit it?

```
populatingLayout() {
    arrayData.map(item => {
        return (
        <div className="FlexRow">
            <div className="FlexColumn">
                <Component dataProp={item} />
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

render() {
     return (
         <div className="FlexGrid">
             {this.populatingLayout()}
         </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered only passing the first 4 values of the array into the map?

Comment: Hi @Shard. Sorry, I don't understand the point of that. What I want is to render all the elements (let's say 20, but could be 500) in rows which contain 4 components per row. It's a kind of grid.

Comment: Ah my mistake @Dubliner I misread the question

Comment: No worries @Shard. I appreciate your interest on the question.

Comment: @Dubliner checkout my answer. Run the snippet below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this. 
Let's just say your elements are 20 div elements in a array. Then you could display each four element in a separate row like this.

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }
   
  
//this function will return array of element 20 divs in this case 
multipleElements() {

   let elements = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            elements.push(
                  <div key={i}> element{i+1} </div>
           )
   }
    return elements;
}

//this function will separate each four element to display 
separateElement () { 
 var separateElements = [];
 var multiElements = this.multipleElements();

for(var i = 0; i < multiElements.length; i+=4) {
     var oneRow = [];
     oneRow.push(multiElements.slice(i, i+4).map(item => {
   return <div style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>{item}</div>
}))
separateElements.push(oneRow.map(itm => {return <div>{itm}</div>}))
}
return separateElements;
}
            
          
            
render() {
   return (<div> {this.separateElement()} </div>);
 }
};

ReactDOM.render(
 <Hello/>,
 document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the style:

```
.row {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}

render() {
     return (
         <div className="FlexGrid">
             <div className="row">
                 arrayData.map(item => <div className="FlexColumn"><Component dataProp={item} /></div>);
             </div>
         </div>
    )
}
```

With this css your row will be the entire width from the father element and your column will be 1/4 width from your row.

Comment: Hi @Alessander. I am using flexbox. Do you think that could be an issue with your suggestion?

Comment: Hi @Dubliner, what exactly are passing at this arrayData? The way you pass this data can affect your loop

Comment: Hi @Alessander. I want to use it for several features. But, for that initial functionality, every element of the array is an object with several properties.

Comment: I used in the past (Angular 1) a way to limit it dynamically. But I think it was based on ng-repeat... Don't remember well.

Comment: Obviously, I need a different approach for React.

Comment: I thought about creating mini arrays... but I wanted a more simple, but dynamic approach.